# Python creating excel files

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

im trying to generate a excel while not deleting the user configuration.
For example you can create here [image]

a new view. And save it.

But when im reading the excel file with pandas or anything else and generate the excel 'the view' would be deleted.

Is there a way where I can create the view in python again? Or dont delete the view?

I looked into some other libraries like openpyxl, xlswriter, but i didnt found any option that can do this.

Comment: I apologize, but I don't quite understand what you're asking.  What is this 'new view' you are referring to?  While I don't understand German,  I'm guessing that's from Excel?    What exactly are you trying to do?   Please clarify.  What code is producing this 'missing view' Excel?

Comment: @ewong Yes, in Excel there is a View menu item where you can create different Sheet Views (same place you would use Freeze Panes)

Comment: maybe you can try build a excel file copy , and output data to this copy to overwrite 
 or modify

Comment: @yangjiang Thats also what I wanted to do. But I dont know if this is possible. Do you know how I can do it in python? Or which library I need to use? Currently im only working with xlswriter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Openpyxl has the functionality to use Sheet Views](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.views.html). I've never used it, so I can't give you specifics. In theory it would allow you to read and rebuild a Sheet View.

Pandas doesn't include that functionality as far as I know. What it does have is the recent ability (and it's also in openpyxl) to append to an existing Excel workbook instead of overwriting.

If you have a Sheet View pointing at a particular sheet, and are adding/editing a *different* sheet, you could use this and it shouldn't impact the sheet view.

If you are editing the sheet the sheet view is pointing at, then you would need to rebuild the view using Openpyxl (but you could still write to it initially with Pandas if that is easier for you).

The code for appending in Pandas is:

```
# use ExcelWriter rather than using to_Excel directly in order to give access to the append & replace functions
with pd.ExcelWriter("data.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, 'My Data', index=False)
```

If you are using openpyxl directly, then `workbook.create_sheet(sheet_name)` will append a new sheet to an existing workbook.

You may find that you have to use win32com, a module which gives you access to some of the functionality that vba has in Excel. The documentation for Views seems scarce though; all I could easily find where these two:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.sheetviews
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheetviews

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tested your code but when I created a view like in my question.
The view disappeared after generating the excel.

Comment: @ColabCoderDE Once you have created the view you have to explicitly save the file, it won't automatically save the changes.

Comment: I created the view in excel. Openend it and justp append a dataframe. Thats it. There was not the view anymore.. @Alan

Comment: Is the view pointing at the sheet you have written? If you overwrite the sheet it will overwrite the view as well, then you need to rebuild it. Otherwise, make sure you are genuinely appending and not overwriting the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module [in2xl](https://pypi.org/project/in2xl/). The module is purely for inserting data into Excel without changing the file.
This means that your view will not be changed.